# Cron expression for every minute from 9:45 until 16:30

Tags: cron

Is it possible to construct a cron expression meaning "every minute from 9:45 until 16:30 of every day"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in same cron expression but you can do something like this :

```
45-59 9 * * * your script
*     10-15 * * * your script
0-30  16 * * * your script
```